# CSS trying to change order of nth-child() div with media query but not working

Tags: html, css

I want to reorder div but it's not working and nav class not showing in the media query after inspect. hoping an expert help.

css code:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:810px) and (min-width:413px) {
    .nav:nth-child(2) {
    order: 2;
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-button">
      <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-button">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-button">
        <a href="#">Catagories</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-button">
        <a href="#">Trending</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-button">
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-button">
        <form action="{{url('/')}}/logout" method="post">
        @csrf
        <button type="submit">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </div>
     <div class="nav-button">
        <a href="#">Log In</a>
    </div>
     <div class="nav-button">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a>
    </div>
     <div class="icon-container nav-button">
         <img src="{{ URL('images/watch/img-2.webp')}}" alt="">
         <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-button">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
    </div>

  </div>
```

if any queries please do me a massage

Comment: If you only have one `.nav` element, then there can't be a `.nav:nth-child(2)`. That means "the second `.nav` instance". Maybe you are trying to target the second `.nav-button` element? Then you want `.nav-button:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: @ 
ralph.m, not working

Answer (score 1):

The `order` property only works inside flex or grid containers.

When you run this snippet, make sure you use the **full screen** link and then resize your browser window to test the responsiveness.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  nav>*:nth-child(1) {
    order: 1;               /* default order is 0 */
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: could you join me in anydesk to check the problem?